# CentOS disk check errors with "Unable to find the checksum in the image"

Tags: centos6

I'm using the CentOS_6.5_Final minimum install ISO. I've added kernel-devel to the Packages directory, and then used `createrepo` to rebuild the metadata.

Creating the repodata when in the `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal` directory.

```
createrepo -p /mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/Packages/
```

It placed the `repodata` in `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/Packages`, so I moved it back to `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/repodata` and replaced the original `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/repodata` with the new directory.

This is how I rebuilt the ISO.

```
genisoimage -o /tmp/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -V OSSA_01 -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T /mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/
```

I used this link as a guide.

[How to create a custom ISO image in CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos)

How do I make sure the image checksum is still valid?

Comment: I guess those checksums are cryptographically signed. If that's the case, you'll have to generate a key pair and use your own public key for validation. But I don't know how to actually update the public key or the checksums. I am wondering if superusers or stackoverflow would have been more appropriate for this question.

Comment: I assume you are referring to `RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-XXXX` in the root of the ISO..