# How to create CentOS7 ISO image with kickstart file?

Tags: centos7, kickstart, disk-image

I'm trying to create a CentOS 7 ISO image to use it later with Virtualbox. That ISO should include a `ks.cfg` file also.

I've followed the steps under [How to create a custom ISO image in CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos), but I get one ISO with only 70MB of size which cannot be used in Virtualbox.

Any user guide or something to follow?

Comment: This URL perhaps, http://smorgasbork.com/2014/07/16/building-a-custom-centos-7-kickstart-disc-part-1/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to create custom DVD from the RHEL7 page.

1. Mount the downloaded image.

   ```
   mount -t iso9660 -o loop path/to/image.iso /mnt/iso
   ```
2. Create a working directory - a directory where you want to place the contents of the ISO image.

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/ISO
   ```
3. Copy all contents of the mounted image to your new working directory.

   ```
   cp -pRf /mnt/iso /tmp/ISO
   ```

   Make sure to use the `-p` option to preserve file and directory permissions and ownership.
4. Unmount the image.

   ```
   umount /mnt/iso
   ```
5. Make sure your current working directory is the top-level directory of the extracted ISO image - e.g. `/tmp/ISO/iso`. Create the new ISO image using `genisoimage`:

   ```
   genisoimage -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "RHEL-7.1 Server.x86_64" -Volset "RHEL-7.1 Server.x86_64" -A "RHEL-7.1 Server.x86_64" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o ../NEWISO.iso .
   ```

Hope the [Anaconda Customization Guide - Images Repack](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux/version-7.1/red-hat-enterprise-linux-71-anaconda-customization-guide/#sect-images-repack) will helpful too.

Comment: can you summarize what's on the doc page so future visitors don't need to click to see what's there? Welcome to Server Fault - this looks like a great start of an answer, but really needs to be fleshed-out some more :)