# How to create a custom CentOS 7 ISO with .img?

Tags: centos, centos7, iso

I'm trying to create a custom CentOS 7 `.iso` that has a set of scripts included, eg. `installX.sh`.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/anaconda_customization_guide/sect-iso-images), creating a `product.img` with the file structure: `/sbin/installX.sh`, `/.buildstamp`

I then placed that in the `images` folder and generated the `.iso`. However, when testing out the `.iso`, it doesn't have `installX.sh` anywhere on the system when running `find / -name installX.sh`. This suggests the `product.img` file was ignored.

How can I load an `.img` file into the file structure of the installed OS?

The contents of `.buildstamp`:

```
[Main]
Product=CentOS Linux
Version=7.7
BugURL=https://bugs.centos.org
IsFinal=True
[Compose]
Lorax=19.6.92-1
```

The image file was created using this command:

```sh
find . | cpio -c -o | gzip -9cv > ../product.img
```

And was placed in `linux/images` in the ISO path

To generate the `.iso`, I used this command:

```sh
genisoimage -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "CentOS 7 x86_64" -volset "CentOS 7 x86_64" -A "CentOS 7 x86_64" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o ../CentOS7.iso .
```

Where the working directory is the file structure to become the `.iso`, and `CentOS7.iso` is the `.iso` I'm trying to create.

The `.iso` was checksummed using:

```sh
implantisomd5 ../CentOS7.iso
```

And was working and able to be installed as a normal CentOS 7 installation (Just without `installX.sh`).

Comment: May be you will gate some input from following questions
[Centos7](https://serverfault.com/questions/892372/i-am-trying-to-create-custom-centos-7-iso-but-in-my-iso-software-selection-list)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this would be to convert the `.img` to cd9660 format. Then [mount](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=mount&sektion=0&manpath=Red%20Hat%20Linux%2Fi386%209&arch=default&format=html) it, and copy what you need on to the CentOS iso image you're building. You can accomplish the conversion using **iat**. For example, if I were on Ubuntu. I'd do it this way:

```
sudo apt install iat
```

followed by

```
iat yourimge.img youriso.iso
```

Then simply mount the freshly converted iso image in the same way you [mount](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=mount&sektion=0&manpath=Red%20Hat%20Linux%2Fi386%209&arch=default&format=html)ed the CentOS iso. Copy the files you need to the CentOS image you're creating where you need them.

Comment: This method will allow me to access the files on the `.img` and relies on being able to copy the file directly onto the mounted CentOS `.iso`, however the CentOS `.iso` has an install file structure with the filestructure hidden inside other `.img` files. It doesn't seem recommended to change these existing files meaning there's no way to directly add to the `.iso` without creating a `.img` for Anaconda to pick up.

Comment: OK I've re-read your question. It appears that your image was not found _because_ the ISO image wasn't created properly. It _appears_ that (as you say) **your** image wasn't included in the new ISO. What was the _exact_ command you used to create the new ISO?

Comment: See updates in question

Comment: Thanks for the update @JosephKeane I'm on a BSD, and use [mkisofs](https://manpage.me/?mkisofs) which is also available for Linux. Let me get back to you after I've whipped up the incantation for your needs. :)