# CentOS7 Kickstart issue

Tags: centos7, kickstart

I've prepared a **ks.cfg** file and validated it with *ksvalidator*, however it doesn't seem to do what I wish it was doing. 
For example - it keeps going into graphical mode despite specifying *text* option. Next it stops at language section, just so I would click "Continue" and doesn't seem to pick the language settings I have specified.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvrOa.png)

After that it stops on "Installation Summary" section where I need to open "System" settings and click "Done" for it to proceed. It prompts the message that automated partitioning has been selected, however I have specified in my file what partitions I want to have created and removed the "autopart" option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J36mM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONRg8.png)

Question is if my Kickstart file is incorrect, or maybe I'm missing some switches or messed up with settings order?
Below the updated config:

```
#version=DEVEL
#Action
install

#INSTALLATION SOURCE SETTINGS:
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
text
# Accept Eula
eula --agreed
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=sda

#LANGUAGE/LOCALE SETTINGS:
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=pl --xlayouts='pl'
# System language
lang pl_PL.UTF-8

#NETWORK AND TIME/ZONE SETTINGS:
# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --ipv6=auto --activate
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth1 --onboot=off --ipv6=auto
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth2 --onboot=off --ipv6=auto
network  --hostname=

#USER/AUTHENTICATION SETTINGS:
rootpw --lock
user --groups=wheel --name= --password=

# SYSTEM SERVICES
services --enabled=chronyd, strongswan
# System timezone
timezone Europe/Warsaw --isUtc --ntpservers=0.centos.pool.ntp.org,1.centos.pool.ntp.org,2.centos.pool.ntp.org,3.centos.pool.ntp.org
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
part /boot --fstype=xfs --onpart=sda1 --size=512
part /root --fstype=xfs --onpart=sda2 --size=4096
part swap --fstype=swap --size=1024

#PACKAGES
%packages
@^minimal
@core
chrony
kexec-tools
strongswan

%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'

%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end
```

I've deleted the user details for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The `cmdline` option only works on System Z (s390x) installations.

To install in text mode, use the `text` option.

Further, your kickstart doesn't specify a recognized locale. It says:

```
lang en_US
```

But this also needs to specify an encoding, e.g.:

```
lang en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I've tried it this way as well but sadly no luck.

Comment: OK, what errors did you receive?

Comment: ksvalidator returned no errors. all I'm wishing for is the installation process that will not require any input/action on client's side as I have to deploy this system in many locations.

Comment: I didn't ask about ksvalidator. I asked what errors occurred when you tried to install the system with this kickstart.

Comment: Like it is written in the original post - it does not give error however makes the installation not 100% automated. It still requires client's action, which I have already described and attached pictures of.

Comment: The pictures you attached are examples, they are not from your actual attempt at installation. And you should change to the other virtual terminals during the installation to view logs.

Comment: The pictures that I have attached are the exact stage pictures I'm getting at the installation. I do terminate installation and work on the file before running it for the second time. I manage installation locally on my PC using VirtualBox.

Comment: Those pictures are not from CentOS 7. What is really going on here?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But they show exactly the same as it appears during CentOS7 installation, no I thought there is no point to look for different ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by creating .iso file with ks.cfg file within it according to following topic:
[How to create a custom ISO image in CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos)